# Plotting rescaled time series and temporal data

Tags: time-series, missing

I am trying to use ListLinePlot to plot three "Components" of my TemporalData in Mathematica. The three components differ widely in the range of the data. So, I want to Rescale each component and plot.

I used the Rescale function on each "Components". This works well if there is no missing data in the Component. However, it does not plot if there is missing data. I know there is a RescaleTimeSeries function to scale the time axis. Is there a corresponding function for the y-axis.

@Gladaed, Here is an example with two components:

```
r = {11, 13, 2, 7, 17, 8};
s = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
td = TemporalData[{r, s}, {t}]

rmissing = {11, 13, Missing["No Data"], 7, 17, 8};
tdmissing = TemporalData[{rmissing, s}, {t}]

grp0 = ListLinePlot[td]
grpmissing = ListLinePlot[tdmissing]

grp1 = ListLinePlot[{Rescale[td["Components"][[1]]], Rescale[td["Components"][[2]]]}]
grprescaledandmissing = ListLinePlot[{Rescale[tdmissing["Components"][[1]]], Rescale[tdmissing["Components"][[2]]]}]
```

You will see that the Rescaled Plot "grprescaledandmissing" does not plot the Component with missing data. The regular ListLinePlot "grpmissing" that is not Rescaled is fine.

Comment: Can you provide examples? i would guess that Show might help but that's just a wild guess right now. In general try to provide a minimal working example. A lot of questions are solved while constructing such example and if they are not, they are easier to answer due to the example.

Comment: @Gladaed, Here is an example: 

    r = {11, 13, 2, 7, 17, 8};
    s = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
    t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
    td = TemporalData[{r, s}, {t}]

    rmissing = {11, 13, Missing["No Data"], 7, 17, 8};
    tdmissing = TemporalData[{rmissing, s}, {t}]

    grp0 = ListLinePlot[td]
    grpmissing = ListLinePlot[tdmissing]

    grp1 = ListLinePlot[{Rescale[td["Components"][[1]]], 
   Rescale[td["Components"][[2]]]}]

 grpmissing = 
 ListLinePlot[{Rescale[tdmissing["Components"][[1]]], 
   Rescale[tdmissing["Components"][[2]]]}]

Comment: The reason you're having issues is because `Rescale` does not know how you'd prefer `Missing` to be handled so it returns a symbolic output which in turn doesn't plot. Perhaps you should consider using the [`ResamplingMethod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html?q=ResamplingMethod) option or handle the missing data manually (hand code it to a numeric value eg `0` if applicable for the use case at hand)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by the way Mathematica's Plot function handles missing data. It assumes it to be eg. a potentially noisy dataset where interpolating could lead to false assumptions about the dataset.

EG:
A vibration/motion sensor gives us information about the quality of a measurement. Less variance the better. It measures tries to measure this:

[image: real noise]

But since it only can measure once every 10th part of a second it gives us:

[image: measured noise]

which is good. But now the sensor had a loose connection now it gave temporal data with some Missing[] elements. If it assumed it should interpolate it would give this curve below. While it is a little obvious for this example imagine more smaller sections of missing data. This could do serious damage to you project if you don't know about this behaviour.

[image: loose connection with interpolation]

Now you would think that the data is way less noisy than it actually is instead of noting the lack of data like this:

[image: loose connection without interpolation]

That's why you have to tell TemporalData via MissingDataMethod what to do in such cases if you want some fixing of missing points. Found using: [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Mathematica%20DeleteMissing%20Temporal%20Data&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Code:

```
randomList = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
t = Range[-5, 5, 10.0/(100 - 1)];
randomTD = TemporalData[randomList, {t}]
randomList[[40 ;; 60]] = Missing["loose connection"]
randomMissingTD = TemporalData[randomList, {t}]
randomMissingInterpolTD = 
 TemporalData[randomList, {t}, 
  MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation"}]
Plot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {x, -5, 5}]
ListLinePlot[randomTD]
ListLinePlot[randomMissingTD]
ListLinePlot[randomMissingInterpolTD]
```

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue. It appears the problem is because of the Rescale function I used. I tried the MissingDataMethod->{"Interpolation"} on a small dataset and it works. However, when I tried to use it on a larger TemporalData variable (that was defined in function), it did not. What is the difference between MissingDataMethod and ResamplingMethod?

Comment: @Murali I do not know. I am sorry i did not answer in a while. Can you provide a example that reproduces your issue? E.g. with RandomInteger[2, 10^6]

Comment: I resolved the issue. I had to rewrite my version of Rescale, which did not handle Missing[] well. I extracted the rescaling factor from the numeric (non-missing) data and replotted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Murali You can Accept answers on SE such that other people know this has been solved well enough and people having similair issues can find the best answer easily.

Comment: `MissingDataMethod` controls what values that are explicitly `Missing[]` are replaced with - a constant or an interpolated value, etc. `ResamplingMethod` defines how the values between time stamps are computed (hold the value from the left or use interpolation, etc.)